# What else to change or standardize in cloning Linux as Virtual Machine?

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, vmware-esxi, cloning

What would be the thing to consider in making multiple copies of Linux as VM ?
in Windows i know there is sysprep to generate random SSID and make it unique copy. 
Can anyone share it here please ?

Thanks,

Albert

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the latest vmtools are installed and your time-sync choice is in and working fully. I'd also be tempted to put chef or puppet in too.

Comment: yes that is of course a must :-), with the Ubuntu 10.04 LTS as the OS and then I make the NIC: VMXNet3 with LSI Logic SAS as the SCSI Controller.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how paranoid you probably want to regenerate your SSH host keys, it isn't required but the more copies of your host keys that exist, the more likely they are to be compromised making a MITM attack possible.

If the VMs are joined to a Windows domain you will need to change the name and rejoin the domain using the alternate name.

There may be other service specific things to fix, but you haven't told us much about what are running on these VMs.

Comment: Nothing run yet Zoredache, it will be for web server or some build server.

Comment: thanks for your reply man, It will be a general purpose VM templates for example i can deploy web application on top of it like Mantis, Wiki, jira ,etc. none of them joined to the Windows AD domain.